# jqGrid not displaying data but paging and column names are displayed/working fine

Tags: c#, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been following the tutorials at https://tpeczek.codeplex.com/ to get jqGrid working and after updating my GetData() actionresult to enable paging and sorting and now my grid no longer displays the data but I am not sure why as no errors are behing thrown. The code that used to work:

```
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            var model = (from s in db.Sections
                         select new
                         {
                             s.ID,
                             s.RouteName,
                             s.Title
                         }).ToList();
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

my new code attempting to add paging and sorting.

public ActionResult GetData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            try
            {
                int RowCount = db.Sections.Count();
                int SkipCount = (page * rows);

```
            string OrderBy = (sidx + " " + sord);

            var SectionData = new
            {
                total = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)RowCount / (float)rows),
                page = page,
                records = RowCount,
                rows = (from s in db.Sections
                        select new
                        {
                            id = s.ID,
                            cell = new string[] {
                                SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.ID).Trim(),
                                s.RouteName,
                                s.Title
                            }
                            .OrderBy(x => sidx)
                            .Skip(SkipCount)
                            .Take(rows)
                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(SectionData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

EDIT:
jqGrid Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function ()
{
    $( '#Sections' ).jqGrid( {
        url: '/Admin/Section/GetData',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'RouteName', 'Title'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: '10' },
                    { name: 'RouteName', index: 'RouteName', width: '50' },
                    { name: 'Title', index: 'Title' }
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        height: '100%',
        pager: $( '#SectionsPager' ),
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'ID',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true
    } ).navGrid(
       '#SectionsPager',
       //enabling buttons
       { add: true, del: false, edit: false, search: false },
       //edit options
       { width: 'auto' },
       //add options
       { width: 'auto', url: '/Admin/Section/Add' },
       //delete options
       {} );
} );
```

Comment: @Eagle..please show code for jqgrid..there may be the mistake

Comment: @Avinash Sorry about that was rushing out to work and forgot it. I have added it in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up adding the command `loadonce: true` to the jqGrid config to enable client side sorting and have removed all code on the server side dealing with sorting. My grid is now displaying the data and sorting and paging fine.

Comment: @Matthew..Firstly , there are two ways of sorting in jqgrid. server side and client side. You have not mentioned any your requirement i.e whether you want client side or server side. Secondly, since your code resembles server side paging , i added the answer. So, please think before you downvote , mention your requirement properly in the question. The Question you have asked , and the answer you have answerd for it , will defenitely mislead many users of SO. It is beacuse , your queustion deals about server side paging and answer is for client side paging.

Comment: @Avinash I down voted you because your suggest to add the `datatype: "json"` was already in my code and your suggest to remove `loadOnce: true` from my code when it was not there. Your answer provided no insight into the problem or solution. My question does have server side code in it but there was no requirement to have it on either the server or client side so my answer does solve the problem of getting paging to work. There are plenty of question on SO where people try to do things one way and the best answer is to do it another, this would be one of those times.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set : `datatype: "json"` and if at all you are using `loadOnce:true`  remove that..

Comment: According to the jqGrid documentation the default setting of loadOnce is false.